# SOAP function giving me a 500 error

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm trying to connect to a soap api, but every time i try and call a function i get a 500 internal error.

I able able to call $client->__getFunctions() with out any issue, so i'm guessing that the code was able to connect to the soap server ok? I can see the function that i'm trying to call in the array:

```
GetCatalogFullResponse GetCatalogFull(GetCatalogFull $parameters)
```

heres my code:

```
$GUID = '000-000-000-000';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'pass';
$url = 'https://example.net/webservices.asmx?WSDL';
$localCert = "cert.pem";

$options = array(
    'local_cert' => $localCert,
    'user' => $user,
    'passphrase' =>$pass,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    );

try {
    $client = new SoapClient($url, $options);
    $result = $client->GetCatalogFull(['AccountGUID'=>$GUID,'UserLogin'=>$user]);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($client->__getFunctions());

} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

this is the request i am trying to make with the soap client class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap12:Body>
<GetCatalogFull xmlns="http://www.example.com">
      <AccountGUID>string</AccountGUID>
      <UserLogin>string</UserLogin>
    </GetCatalogFull>
</soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Comment: The error is occurring on the server. Are there any log files on the server?

Comment: If you don't have access to the server which is handling the API request, then I'm not sure anyone can help you. You would need to contact the developers of said API

Comment: i am able to assess the WSDL, does that make a difference?